# A weird trigonometry identity applied to get the same result

Tags: pstricks

The following two input files produce the same output.

### Method 1:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{PosAngle={-135,90},CurveType=polyline}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](4,4)
\pstGeonode
    (1,1){O}
    (4,3){A}
\uput{1}%
    [!3 1 sub 4 1 sub atan]
    {!3 1 sub 4 1 sub atan}(O){$\pi-\theta$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Method 2:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{PosAngle={-135,90},CurveType=polyline}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](4,4)
\psset{linecolor=red}
\pstGeonode
    (1,1){O}
    (4,3){A}
\uput{1}%
    [!\psGetNodeCenter{A}\psGetNodeCenter{O} A.y O.y sub A.x O.x sub atan]
    {!\psGetNodeCenter{A}\psGetNodeCenter{O} A.y O.y sub neg A.x O.x sub atan}(O){$\pi-\theta$}
\end{pspicture}    

\end{document}
```

The question is why do I have to express `3 1 sub 4 1 sub atan` in the first method as
`A.y O.y sub neg A.x O.x sub atan` in the second method while

`A.y` equals to 3

`O.y` equals to 1

`A.x` equals to 4

`O.x` equals to 1

?

In other words, why do I need to add `neg` for the first argument of `atan` in the second method?

Comment: Node is the most unpredictable creature in PSTricks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes are saved in an own dictionary which also saves the current transformation matrix which is restored when using `\psGetNodeCenter`. To rotate back you have to use the negative rotation angle:

```
{!\psGetNodeCenter{A}\psGetNodeCenter{O} A.y O.y sub A.x O.x sub atan neg}(O){$\pi-\theta$}
```

`neg` must be used at the end. However it gives the same result when using for y

Comment: One question: but why don't we need `neg` in `[!\psGetNodeCenter{A}\psGetNodeCenter{O} A.y O.y sub A.x O.x sub atan]`?

Answer (score 1):

With the latest PSTricks packages, the problem no longer exists.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{PosAngle={-135,90},CurveType=polyline}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](4,4)
\psset{linecolor=red}
\pstGeonode
    (1,1){O}
    (4,3){A}
\uput{1}%
    [!N-A.y N-O.y sub N-A.x N-O.x sub atan]
    {!N-A.y N-O.y sub N-A.x N-O.x sub atan}(O){$\pi-\theta$}
\end{pspicture}    

\end{document}
```